# Angularjs browser back button stops partials from loading and causes page refreshes

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that behaves normally when I follow links on the page, but if I use the browser's back and forward buttons, it breaks in the following ways:

1. It sends a request to the server, but only on "Back".
2. The template is not rendered at all.

In addition, when I hit "back" to go from page B to page A, chrome's "refresh/stop" button flickers between the top options rapidly, and repeated attemptes to go back and forward causes longer flickering.

Here are the code snippets that I think are relevant:

*Edit: I'm working on a plnkr but the site is currently not working. I'll update when it's up and I can verify the bad behavior*

Edit 2: Here is the plnkr, but it has problems. It can't find the templateUrls specified in app.js routing, not sure why. Here's the code anyway http://plnkr.co/edit/6cQtnvLi10sJKW8jVzVM

Edit 3: With the help of a friend, I think the problem is coming from using turbo-links on rails 4. I can't test it right now, but when I can I'll post an answer if it works.

### file: app.js

```
window.App = angular.module('app', [
    'templates',
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'home.html'
            })
            .when('/bars', {
                    controller: 'BarsPublicCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'bars_public.html'
            })
            .when('/bars/:bar_name', {
                controller: 'BarsDetailPublicCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'bars_detail_public.html'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

### file: bars_public_ctrl.js

```
 App.controller('BarsPublicCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'BarsPublicDataFactory',
        function($scope, $location, BarsPublicDataFactory) {
                // memoization
                $scope.bars = $scope.bars || BarsPublicDataFactory.getBars();
      }
    ]);
```

BarsPublicDataFactory just returns a static array of fake data, same with the factory in the following snippet

### file: bars_detail_public_ctrl.js

```
App.controller('BarsDetailPublicCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'BarsDetailPublicDataFactory',
    function($scope, $routeParams, BarsDetailPublicDataFactory) {
      $scope.bar = {};
      $scope.bar.name = $routeParams.barId;
      $scope.barDetails = BarsDetailPublicDataFactory.getBaz($routeParams.bar_name);
      $scope.Bazs = BarsDetailPublicDataFactory.getBazs();
}]);
```

### file: bars_public.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="bar in bars">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="/bars/{{bar.name}}">
                    <h4 style="display:inline;">{{ bar.name }}</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

### file: bars_detail_public.html

```
<select ng-model="searchSelect.style" style="width:100%;">
    <option value='' selected>All</option>
    <option ng-repeat="baz in bazs">{{baz}}</option>
</select>
<div>
    <accordion close-others="true">
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="foo in foos | filter:searchSelect">
            <accordion-heading>
                <div>
                    <h3>{{foo.name}}</h3>                
                    <em>{{foo.style}}</em>
                </div>
            </accordion-heading>
        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

If you need anything else, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was caused by turbolinks with Rails 4. I failed to mention it because I didn't realize it was important.

I don't know exactly what caused it, but turbolinks injects some javascript, and as best as I can tell, it highjacks some events that cause the page to reload when you use the browse buttons which was breaking my app.

So I followed this advice: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4
and it worked just fine! Hope someone else can benefit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been the most bizarre bug in our Angular app and we spent a ton of time debugging it...and your answer came to rescue.

Answer (score 0):

befoure:
[installed]jquery_turbo_links
[installed]turbolinks

alter:
[installed]jquery_turbo_links
[removed]turbolinks

It worked!